# Dynamically Writing Vars to a Webpage

Tags: javascript

I have the following function below and it works great when all 3 vars are not null, however, how can it be modified such that when either variable (tel, fax, cell) are null, that the line containing the null variable does not get written?

```
Current scenario:
T. 123-4567-8910
F. 987-654-3210
C. 
-------------------------------
Desired scenario:
T. 123-4567-8910
F. 987-654-3210
-------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {

var tel = "123-4567-8910"
var fax = "987-654-3210"
var cell = ""

var html =
        '<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n' +
        '<div>F. '+ fax +'</div>\n' +
        '<div>C. '+ cell +'</div>'

document.write(html)

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me introduce you to conditional statements:

```
var html = '';
if (tel) {
  html += '<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n';
}
if (fax) {
  html += '<div>F. '+ fax +'</div>\n';
}
if (cell) {
  html += '<div>C. '+ cell +'</div>\n';
}
document.write(html)
```

Although `document.write()` is usually considered a bad idea. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write).

Comment: I think `document.write` is perfectly fine inline the HTML since the document is open (not that I'd ever use it myself). The trouble is when you try to use it after the document has loaded. But now I am noticing that the `document.write` is in a function call (a click event) where it shouldn't be used

Comment: @Ian That is also one of the issues.

Comment: What else are you referring to then? From the link, the text "does not work in XHTML documents"?

Comment: @Ian I mean issues with the users JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var tel = "123-4567-8910";
            var fax = "987-654-3210";
            var cell = "";

            var html = "";

            if (tel == "") {
                html = html + '<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n';
            }
            if (fax == "") {
                html =  html + '<div>F. '+ fax +'</div>\n';
            }
            if (cel == "") {
                html = html + '<div>C. '+ cel +'</div>\n';
            }
            document.append(html);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this? There is no `empty()` function in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, and so was the `.=`... So many languages, so little time. Thank you for the saves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test each variable:

```
var html =
    ((tel)?'<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n':'') +
    ((fax)?'<div>F. '+ fax +'</div>\n':'') +
    ((cell)?'<div>C. '+ cell +'</div>':'') ;
document.write(html);
```

How it works:

```
(tel)?'<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n':''
```

means: if tel is not empty/null then `'<div>T. '+ tel +'</div>\n'` else `''`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gHdy8/

Comment: @user1451890 some parentheses were missing, sorry about that. Corrected now, and live demo added.